# How to select in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Consider the following nested list:

```
fff = {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}}}, {2, 
   8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}, {20, 21}}}}
```

Each of the entries in list has the form:

```
{a,b,table}
```

I would like to remove `table` rows for which the first element is `> 3`, i.e. to obtain

```
fff' = {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {2, 
       8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}
```

Is it possible with a help of one command such as Select?

Comment: *which the first element is <=3,*  I think you meant  `>3` there?

Comment: @Nasser : no, why?

Comment: Because that is what you show as your desired output? It has all entries where the first element which is >3 was removed?

Comment: Ah, yes, excuse me. You are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[Join, {#[[1 ;; 2]] & /@ 
   fff, #[[All, 3, All]] &@fff /. {x_, y_} /; x > 3 -> Nothing}]
```

---

Using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[If[First@# > 3, Nothing, #] &, fff, {All, 3, All}]
```

---

Using `Select`:

```
MapAt[Select[#, First@# <= 3 &] &, fff, {All, 3}]
```

---

Result:

> {{1, 2, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2,    8, {0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2,
> 18}, {0.3, 19}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list =
  {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}}},
   {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}, {20, 21}}}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {a_ /; a > 3, _}, ∞]
```

> {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}

Or using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, s : {a_ /; a > 3, _} :> Nothing, {1, Depth@list}]
```

> {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. {a_ /; a > 3, _} :> Nothing
```

> {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}}},
   {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}, {20, 21}}}};
```

Positional solutions

```
p = Position[list, {a_, _} /; a > 3]
```

> {{1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 6}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ list
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

All return:

> {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}},
> {2, 8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
fff = {{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}}}, {2, 
    8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}, {20, 21}}}};
assn = Association[{#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ fff];
KeyValueMap[Join[#1, {#2}] &, 
 DeleteCases[#, {a_?(# > 3 &), _}] & /@ assn]
```

yields:

{{1, 2, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {2,
8, {{0.5, 3}, {1.4, 2}, {3, 13}, {2, 18}, {0.3, 19}}}}